# Allow touch events only on some selected labels of view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am a newbie in iPhone development, doing my first app.

I have some labels on screen

out of these labels I have to appy drag event on few selected

code for dragging is

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Retrieve the touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Move relative to the original touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setFrame:frame];
}
```

now I want that drag only implement to few selected labels.

I implemented this by subclassing UILabel

```
@interface DragView : UILabel
{
    CGPoint startLocation;
}
@end

@implementation DragView
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Retrieve the touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Move relative to the original touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setFrame:frame];
}
@end
```

but I want to implemet this without subclassing

is there any way to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`userInteractionEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) property of the `UILabel` to `NO`.